# Thumbnail style in note pages with beamer

Tags: beamer, header-footer, color, notes

I'm making a presentation with LaTeX beamer and editing some notes about the frames.

I managed to change the background color of notes with `\setbeamercolor{note page}` but I still have a white background in the frame thumbnail (at the top right of the note page).

The problem is that on my presentation frames, my texts are white on a colored background :

[image]

and the thumbnails background become white in the note page in addition of  deleting the top (navigation) and bottom (title) bars. thumbnail are not readable anymore.

[image]

Is it possible to get the thumbnails showing exactly what we see on frames ?

If not, is it possible to modify the text and background colors inside the thumbnails, by modifying a LaTeX command or setting a specific beamer style (like `\setbeamercolor{background canvas}` for frames) ?

Comment: Could you add a Minimal Working Example? Form `\documentclass` to \end{document}`. Making reference to all themes and packages you use, to show the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`beamer` uses `\insertslideintonotes` to insert a frame thumbnail into notes page. This command is defined in `beamerbasenotes.sty` file:

```
\newcommand{\insertslideintonotes}[1]{{%
  \begin{pgfpicture}{0cm}{0cm}{#1\paperwidth}{#1\paperheight}
    \begin{pgflowlevelscope}{\pgftransformscale{#1}}%
      \color{normal text.bg}
      \pgfpathrectangle{\pgfpointorigin}{\pgfpoint{\paperwidth}{\paperheight}}
      \pgfusepath{fill}
      \color{normal text.fg}
      {\pgftransformshift{\pgfpoint{\beamer@origlmargin}{\footheight}}\pgftext[left,bottom]{\copy\beamer@frameboxcopy}}
    \end{pgflowlevelscope}
  \end{pgfpicture}%
  }}
```

As you can see, it draws a background rectangle with color `normal text.bg` and the frame contents (stored in `\beamer@frameboxcopy`) is added in `normal text.fg` color.

Thus, you need to force `normal text.bg` color to be like the one used in `note page`. As I don't know what could be the effect of changing `normal text` color, another solution would be to change `\insertslideintonotes` definition and use the color you want as background just there. This can be done with next code:

```
\documentclass[notes]{beamer}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\insertslideintonotes}[1]{{%
  \begin{pgfpicture}{0cm}{0cm}{#1\paperwidth}{#1\paperheight}
    \begin{pgflowlevelscope}{\pgftransformscale{#1}}%
      \color{blue!40}  %<-------- Change color here
      \pgfpathrectangle{\pgfpointorigin}{\pgfpoint{\paperwidth}{\paperheight}}
      \pgfusepath{fill}
      \color{normal text.fg}
      {\pgftransformshift{\pgfpoint{\beamer@origlmargin}{\footheight}}\pgftext[left,bottom]{\copy\beamer@frameboxcopy}}
    \end{pgflowlevelscope}
  \end{pgfpicture}%
  }}
\makeatother


\setbeameroption{show notes}
\setbeamercolor{note page}{bg=red!30}
\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=blue!40}
\setbeamercolor{normal text}{fg=white}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
   \blindtext
\end{frame}
\note[itemize]
{\item First note
\item Second note.}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe better than the hardcoding: just put both `\setbeamercolor{normal text}{bg=mycolor}` and `\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=mycolor}` into your preamble. This should also work.